# Homemade double sided PCBs and soldering

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I etched my own double sided PCBs (no plated through holes) and quickly realized that there will be an issue with making sure contacts on both sides of the board are making a proper connection with some components. For example, with some IC sockets, there's no way to solder on the top side of the board, and the solder won't/isn't flowing through the hole because it's not plated.

So please confirm that I have my thought process down when redesigning the layout of the traces:

- With any component in which I cannot get access to from the top side,
  there shouldn't be any traces coming off of those pads
- For those components, a small trace (maybe 1/4" long or so??) with a via should be made from the bottom side back to the top, and then continue the top trace where it needs to go
- For the vias, solder a small wire through the hole on the top and bottom sides so the connection is made
- For other components, such as through hole resistors, and maybe some caps, access to the pad connection from the top may be possible, and I don't have to concern myself with running the via.

Is this essentially right?

Comment: Yes - to all of your points.

Comment: It really depends on your budget and where you live, but you may find that your productivity is far greater if you buy boards from a circuit board aggregator.  2-layer boards with plated through holes are pretty much the standard.  In the US there's at least one place (OshPark) that does all their business with US board houses, meaning you get no-nonsense US quality.  I believe that such places exist in Europe, leveraging the circuit board manufacturing capability in the former Eastern Block countries.  And there's always China, although it seems the quality from there is never as good.

Comment: Seems about right. Welcome to "design for manufacturing"! Note that not only do you not need a trace, you don't need a *pad* on the top side.

Comment: Note that since you are having to do manual jumpers anyway, you might want to re-evaluate whether a double-sided board is worth it, compared to a single-sided board with soldered jumper wires.

Comment: @TimWescott I think the European OSH Park equivalent is Aisler, which is on the Netherlands-Germany border... not quite former eastern block :) Also, for things that you could well make at home, JLCPCB, itead, seeed and all the other Chinese small-run mass board houses really do better than home-etched; by a large margin. Not to mention the ease of design; "I need variable wire jumpers all over the place" is not something modern PCB design software is optimized for.

Comment: If it were a choice between a Chinese aggregator and my own work, I'd go with the Chinese aggregator, for sure.

Comment: Welcome back everyone to the 1970s and 1980s.

Comment: This was the oversight I made in my capstone project. NEVER AGAIN. That board was full of huge components where the leads were under the component so zero chance of ever getting enough access to solder both sides.

Comment: Larry, this is really not saying you *should not* do your own boards – certainly a nice hobby thing, if you're into optimizing a chemical-mechanical process until it works well for your purposes! But it's not going to be cheaper, better, easier or more reliable than ordering a board. That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: @user253751 I've come to that same conclusion, and actually have routed it so very few traces are on the "top" side and will probably do that you're suggesting. My issue with ordering this board out of house at this time is that I want to make sure I created my design properly. The design works on breadboard, but I'm not making any multiple of this--really just a hobby. However I can certainly envision ordering a proper board once all the kinks are worked out.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, maybe. I can knock out a board in about 1/2 hour max. Toner transfer with thin magazine paper works fantastic. I even had no problems lining up the two sides properly.

Comment: @LarryBud really, you etching a single one of these boards, then wasting a lot of wire, solder, flux, nerves… costs you more in material, clean up, health costs than ordering five boards from China, or 3 boards from OSH Park. These things are cheap these days, really really cheap, and you don't have to order 1000s, as said – 3 or 5 or 10 boards are the typical minima. If it works on breadboard, you have a working schematic, and with free software like KiCAD, you can very straightforwardly convert that schematic to a board layout, and check automatically whether it represents your schematic.

Comment: @LarryBud doing some rather interesting hand-etched 1.5-sided board will just add sources of error and uncertainty if something does not work – so the whole argument of "I want to make sure my design is correct" fails due to you then having to make sure 1 your design was valid and 2. your board implementation is valid without good software tools and 3. your etching is good and represents your board layout and 4. your soldering is good and connects all the right things. You basically kill all problems with 2 – 4. by getting a board made! (this is not at all specific to board manufacturing,

Comment: this applies to *any* prototyping, which is why early engineering prototypes are typically made from higher-quality materials by higher-quality externals than the final thing; in your case, the "higher quality engineering prototype" is literally a 5 to 10 USD thing)

Comment: @MarcusMüller are you counting money or time? Larry may be operating in "poor student mode", with lots of time, and not much money. Last I checked, ordering PCBs cost a minimum of $100, which is a lot of money to some people. (The problem is inequitable distribution of goods and services to students, and the solution is to solve capitalism, but that's not going to happen any time soon, so the next best may be to make PCBs at home)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is that why the stolen prototype humanoid battle robots in Japanese shows are always more powerful than their mass production versions?

Comment: This is a hobby for me. I like making stuff. Making PCBs, at this point anyway, is worth the small effort with the large benefit of having a 1/2 hour turnaround, rather than 2-5 days. I can make it, evaluate any design issues that I might have, tweak it, and make another. Blank boards are dirt cheap.

Comment: @user253751 please check again, e.g. jlcpcb.com; I didn't pull these prices out of thin air; you can get 10 piece of 10×10cm boards incl delivery < 10$.

Comment: @DKNguyen yeah! Also, remember Kitt from Knight Rider? That car was also a prototype.

Comment: @LarryBud that's awesome! As said, if you're into the process itself, it might be well worth it. If you just want the results, not so much.